# How to center an image horizontally and align it to the bottom of the container?

Tags: css, positioning

How can I center an image horizontally and aligned to the bottom of the container at the same time?

I have been able to center the image horizontally by its self. I have also been able to align the bottom of the container by its self. But I have not been able to do both at the same time.

Here is what I have:

```
.image_block {
    width: 175px;
    height: 175px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.image_block a img {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
}

<div class="image_block">
    <a href="..."><img src="..." border="0"></a>
</div>
```

That code aligns the image to the bottom of the div. What do I need to add/change to make it also center the image horizontally inside the div? The image size is not known before hand but it will be 175x175 or less.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
.image_block    {
    width: 175px;
    height: 175px;
    position: relative;
}

.image_block a  {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.image_block img    {
/*  nothing specific  */
}
```

**explanation**: an element positioned absolutely will be relative to the closest parent which has a non-static positioning. i'm assuming you're happy with how your `.image_block` displays, so we can leave the relative positioning there.

as such, the `<a>` element will be positioned relative to the `.image_block`, which will give us the bottom alignment. then, we `text-align: center` the `<a>` element, and give it a 100% width so that it is the size of `.image_block`.

the `<img>` within `<a>` will then center appropriately.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. That works perfectly in FF, IE6, IE7, and chrome.

Answer (score 26):

This also works (taken a hint from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520825/vertical-align-image))

```
.image_block {
  height: 175px;
  width:175px;
  position:relative;
}
.image_block a img{
 margin:auto; /* Required */
 position:absolute; /* Required */
 bottom:0; /* Aligns at the bottom */
 left:0;right:0; /* Aligns horizontal center */
 max-height:100%; /* images bigger than 175 px  */
 max-width:100%;  /* will be shrinked to size */ 
}
```

Comment: I strongly prefer this answer. Very nice.

Answer (score 4):

wouldn't

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

added to the `.image_block` a img do the trick?
Note that that won't work in IE6 (maybe 7 not sure)
there you will have to do on `.image_block` the container Div

```
text-align:center;
```

`position:relative;` could be a problem too.

Answer (score 3):

This is tricky; the reason it's failing is that you can't position via margin or text-align while absolutely positioned.

If the image is alone in the div, then I recommend something like this:

```
.image_block {
    width: 175px;
    height: 175px;
    line-height: 175px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

You may need to stick the `vertical-align` call on the image instead; not really sure without testing it.  Using `vertical-align` and `line-height` is going to treat you a lot better, though, than trying to mess around with absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `position: relative;` line. I'm not sure why exactly but it fixes it for me.

Comment: The position:relative on the containing element is required to absolutely position an element within it.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

```
.image_block{
text-align: center;
vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#header2
{
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: bottom;
   background-color:Red;
}


<div style="text-align:center; height:300px; width:50%;" id="header2">
<div class="right" id="header-content2">
  <p>this is a test</p>
</div>
</div>
```