# Vertical-align image

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I have a div that contains an image and a p tag (seen below). I want to align the image in the middle of the div vertically depending on how many lines the paragraph is. Vertical-align doesn't work. I am using JavaScript right now to figure out how much to add to margin-top, but would rather use CSS. Any ideas?

```
<div>
    <img>
    <p>Multi-line</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try setting the `line-height` attribute of the `p` element to the height of the image, eg:

```
div p {
  line-height: 18px;
}
```

**Edit:** Just realised I misread the question and missed the fact the `p` would be multi-line. One option to try is removing the `img` element altogether and setting it as the `background-image` of the `p` instead, with a `background-position` of `left, center`. Something like:

```
div p {
  background: transparent url(path/to/img) no-repeat left center;
  padding-left:30px; /* Set based on width of image */
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution. However in my example, the image will change and will not be a set image.

Comment: You could always set the background-image attribute as an inline style:

<p style="background-image:url(dynamically/generated/path/to/img)">Multi-line</p>

Comment: I could also just set the <p> to a specific class dynamically that will have the different images.

Comment: This won't work if you're trying to style the image (ie: if my image has a border).

Answer (score 59):

This is pure CSS, vertically aligns the image, and also resizes the image down if it's taller (or wider) than the containing box. Ergo, the box and image can both be any size without breaking the vertical alignment. Also, you may want to add a left margin to the `<p>` tags to keep them from being hidden by the image.

### CSS

```css
/* Positioning */
.absoluteCenterWrapper {
    position: relative; /* Contains the image in the div */
}
.absoluteCenter { /* Aligns image vertically */
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.absoluteCenterWrapper p { /* Pushes <p> to edge of image */
    margin-left: 101px; /* Width of image */
}
.absoluteCenter { /* Specifies width of image to avoid overlap if image changes */
    width: 101px; /* Width of image */
}

/* Sizing - resizes down to avoid cutting off */
.absoluteCenter {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

/* Making it "pretty" */
.absoluteCenterWrapper { margin: 1em; padding: 0.001em; /* <- Hack to contain margins */ outline: 1px solid red; }
.absoluteCenterWrapper p { margin-top: 1em; margin-bottom: 1em; padding-left: 1em;}
```

```html
<div class="absoluteCenterWrapper">
 <img class="absoluteCenter" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
 <p>Paragraph goes here.</p>
 <p>Paragraph goes here.</p>
</div>
<div class="absoluteCenterWrapper">
 <img class="absoluteCenter" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
 <p>Paragraph goes here.</p>
 <p>Paragraph goes here.</p>
 <p>Paragraph goes here.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a beautiful solution - thanks so much for sharing! It works well, when nothing else seems to.

Comment: upvoted! For the record, for me it was enough to simply use `margin: auto; position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;` and I had the image in an absolute wrapper, not a relative one.

Comment: `absolute` and `relative` cause the children to behave the same way, so either is acceptable. As for excluding the `max-height`/`max-width`, that only works if you know for a fact your image will *never* be wider/taller than the container. And it doesn't hurt anything to keep it in. Better safe than sorry :P

Comment: I needed to add `left:0;` and `right:0;`. I guess it is because the direct container had no width specified?! Anyway, maybe it helps someone out.

Comment: Nice, tucking this into my tool belt.

Answer (score 1):

Give the image display: block, float: left and vertical-align: middle.  Or, give it a line height equal to that of the containing element.

Answer (score 1):

the CSS vertical-align attributes only works on table cells and inline elements. Since the paragraph tag specifies a block element by default, it does nothing. In order for your text to be aligned as you describe, you either have to separate your div into two containers or use a table. Here's a good page to help you understand a little bit better: [Understanding vertical-align](http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Is it kind of a two column job? (image to the left, text to the right)

If so, you could surely just stick each element in its own div...

```
<div>
    <div style="width:100; float:left"><img /></div>
    <div style="width:100; float:left"><p>multiline</p></div>
</div>
```

Think that would do what you're after

Comment: This won't vertically align them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the solution at [Jak psát web](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html) will help.

Answer (score -1):

Add

```
div img {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Already is floated, maybe should have added that in.

I have the image floating left and the p with a margin-left.

Comment: Will this not just keep in the top left?