# vertical aligning floats

Tags: css

How do I vertical align floating elements?

I currently have 3 elements (an image floated left, another image floated right and a div with a margin:0 centered) in a wrapping div. These are currently aligned at the top but I want them to aling at the bottom of the div.

How can this be achieved without using position absolute on them as this is a responsive layout? I have tried making them `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align: bottom` but that does not help anything.

Comment: Can we see our code, please? The much preferred method is by pasting the relevant parts into www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: [Related question on vertically aligning images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520825/vertical-align-image)

Comment: here is an example of the code. i want the divs to align bottom. http://jsfiddle.net/stinis87/chCjT/6/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/chCjT/16/

Answer (score 2):

In order to use vertical-align on some element, that element must have `display:table-cell;` css style. http://jsfiddle.net/StPYR/

Your jsfiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/chCjT/16/
Instead of floating the elements you need to give them `display:inline-block;` css property

Comment: thanks, that worked very well to align them to the bottom. The only downside is that now they are not floated to their proper side of the page, since it doesnt work when the divs are floated. (remember these divs are examples only, my real divs are floated appropriately on a page with space between em)