# Vertical align image with unknown height and width

Tags: css

So classical css problem, vertical aligning, but this time a bit more complicated, please take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uH4Rn/2/

It is pretty obvious that i want image to be aligned exactly at the middle and as you can see it doesn't work i think problem is with these two lines:

```
top:-25%;
margin-top:-100px;
```

By the way i don't care about IE that much below 9 version and i would like to avoid javascript or jquery.

Comment: Do you want this? http://jsfiddle.net/uH4Rn/6/ I am not sure if this is what it should look like..

Comment: @Usha no, you can see middle line in the image it should be at the center of that div now its below center

Comment: Do you think padding property wrap on image could be at any help? Editing the comments with this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520825/vertical-align-image)

Comment: @bonCodigo can't really see how padding would help when i need image to either go to negative or positive offset depending on it's height

Comment: well i guess if no one have any kind of solution i will have to use js for this :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the previous answer didnt seem to give you the right result, here is another that definatly works. Unless i totally dont understand your question.

This solution will center any image in the given container:

```
.container{
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 300px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uH4Rn/2/