# Clickable div with middle vertical aligned image and text

Tags: html, css

Please see the code below, both image and text are located up in the div.
How to vertical align to the middle, both the image (div_a) and the text (div_txt) inside `<a>`, using pure css, and keep the div clickable (preferred solution with cross browsers compatibility):

```
<style type="text/css">
  a.div_a {
      display:block;
      width:320px;
      height:160px;
      background-color:#CCC;}
</style>

<a href="www.mydoamin.com" class="div_a">
  <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" style="float:left; margin-right:10px; background-color:#666;" />
  <span class="div_txt">Content</span>
</a>
```

I tried the following, but that didn’t help:

```
.div_txt {vertical-align:middle;}
```

I found separated solutions on the above for image/text, but not for both together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `display: table` to your anchor element, and then wrap each your image and span in a `.wrapper` span with the following properties:

```
.wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="www.mydoamin.com" class="div_a">
  <span class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" style="background-color:#666;" />
  </span>

  <span class="wrapper">
    <span class="div_txt">Content</span>
  </span>
</a>
```

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zaknotzak/WcCnW/).

Please note that this approach will not work in IE7, so if IE7 support is a requirement, you will have to use a more elaborate method.

Comment: Thank you all for your professional reply. 
For the simplicity I’ll use @'Zak Angelle' solution.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [Vertical-align image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520825/vertical-align-image/6295861#6295861) and altered slightly to account for `<a>` ([jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dS2GT/152/)):

### Extra markup for link

```
a.absoluteCenterWrapper {
 display:block;
}
```

### CSS

```css
.absoluteCenterWrapper {
 position:relative; /* Contains the image in the div */
}

/* Positioning */
.absoluteCenter {
 margin:auto; /* Required */
 position:absolute; /* Required */
 top:0;bottom:0; /* Aligns Vertically */
}

/* Sizing - resizes down to avoid cutting off */
.absoluteCenter { /* Fallback Sizing */
 max-height:100%;
 max-width:100%;
}
```

### HTML

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/" class="absoluteCenterWrapper">
 <img src="PATHTOIMAGE" class="absoluteCenter">
 <p>Paragraph goes here.</p>
</a>
```