# vertical-align an image at centre of div

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I want to vertical-align and also horizontal align an image at the centre of a div. Currently my code only works with the horizontal-align and now I want to vertically align it as well. Can you please help me?

Here is my css code:

```
.centre
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

img
{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: This question has been asked and answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520825/vertical-align-image

Answer (score 1):

Just use  `display:table-cell;` on `.centre`. Here's an example that shows it clearly, just change the selectors accordingly. http://jsfiddle.net/Y6NTf/

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to set the `img` `position` to relative and the `top` and `left` to `50%`. [Here](http://jsbin.com/okigoz/1/) is a full working example.

HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv">
  <img id="myImg" src="http://i.cdn.turner.com/cnn/.element/img/3.0/global/header/hat/arrow_black.png"></img>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#myDiv {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: grey;
}

#myImg {
  position:relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Ok so I tried your example. The problem is that it gets centred from the top left corner of the image and not from the centre of the image. Knows how to fix that?

Comment: @David: This solution requires knowing the size of the image, and setting a negative left and top margin equal to half the width and height of the image, respectively.

Comment: Yes I do know the size of the image so I tried padding-top and pading-left but of course it does work with a negative amount of px

Comment: @David: a negative *margin*, not negative padding

Comment: Thanks a lot worked perfectly