# How to horizontally align an img to the center inside the list items

Tags: css

Here is my page structure;

[image]

I have images inside all "li" below. I am trying to align these images inside the li elements. I am trying to do this with setting right and left margin to auto but it is not working.

Here is the css;

```
#navcontainer ul li
{
    display: inline-block;
    width:80px;
}

#navcontainer ul li img
{
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
}
```

I am sure it is not about accessing the element from css, bcs when I set the width or height or any other thing in the css it is working. But I didnt manage to align it to the center.

Comment: Align them *how*, or *where*?

Comment: Also you have a HTML markup error, you can not place an a-tag inside the ul.

Comment: @David Thomas, horizontally, center.

Comment: Why don't you google your own question?
This is what I found...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299870/how-to-center-an-image-horizontally-and-align-it-to-the-bottom-of-the-container

Comment: @Cadence96 the post you found is not the same with this one, I mean the question is different but answer is same yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they're `inline-block`, simply use `text-align: center` on the parent `li` elements.

If they're `display: block`, then you can use `margin: 0 auto 0 auto` (`top`,`right`,`bottom` `left`).

It's also worth pointing out that the ***only*** valid children of a `ul` or `ol` are `li` elements. Any *other* content *must* be wrapped in an `li`, otherwise the mark-up is invalid, and then the user-agent tries to correct the mark-up when preparing the DOM. And not consistently across the various user-agents.

Using the following mark-up as a demonstration:

```
<ul>
    <li class="inlineBlock"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports" /></li>
    <li class="block"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature" /></li>
</ul>​
```

With the following CSS:

```
li.inlineBlock {
    text-align: center;
}
li.inlineBlock img {
    display: inline-block;
}

li.block img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WEVZq/).